# Не получается настроить IPv6 в Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, сеть

Взял VPS, где для включения IPv6 необходимо убрать комментарии со строк конфигурации в `/etc/network/interfaces`. Получилось так:

```
iface ens3 inet6 static
address 2001:41d0:302:2200::f32
gateway 2001:41d0:302:2200::1
netmask 128
dns-nameservers 2001:4860:4860::8888 2001:4860:4860::8844
post-up /sbin/ip -6 route add 2001:41d0:302:2200::f32 dev eth0
post-up /sbin/ip -6 route add default via 2001:41d0:302:2200::f32 dev eth0
pre-down /sbin/ip -6 route del default via 2001:41d0:302:2200::f32 dev eth0
pre-down /sbin/ip -6 route del 2001:41d0:302:2200::f32 dev eth0
```

Но IPv6 так и не заработал.

При попытке пропинговать IPv6 сервер получаю ошибку:

> connect: Network is unreachable

Что я сделал не так?

Comment: что пишет при попытке использовать ipv6?

Comment: @user232384 протупил добавить вывод консоли в вопрос.